# Set UWP app display resolution

Tags: uwp, smart-tv, xbox-one

My company has developed a Smart TV VOD app in HTML/JS that runs on numerous platforms (Samsung, LG, Philips, Panasonic, Sony and PlayStation).  All of those devices support 1280x720 screen resolution and so the CSS layout has been hard coded for that resolution.

We now wish to port it to XBox One as a UWP app. It boots up and runs ok in Visual Studio, however we can't see anything in the docs to set the screen res to 1280x720.

Is there a setting we need in the config file, an API call to set the resolution or scale, or are we just going to have to scale the CSS co-ords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the screen resolution from the app - there's no config or API for that. You'll need to scale the app up. (Or maybe try using a XAML `webview` that's set to 1280x720 and sits in a `viewbox` which scales it up.)

Comment: Thanks Tamás.  I'll look into XAML, otherwise I guess I'll just integrate a css pre-scaler (https://github.com/meerkats/gulp-scale-css) into our Gulp file.